# Show realtime output of subprocess in a QDialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, subprocess, pyqt5

I have a script that activates a virtual environment and runs `pip` commands inside it. For that I first create a `bash` script with the needed commands and pass the final command (which finally runs the script) to `run_script()` which produces an output line by line. The subprocess works fine as well as printing the output to a console.

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is to display the catched realtime output (that comes line by line) of `run_script()` (which shows the installation progress of `pip install ...`) together with a `QProgressBar` in a `QDialog`.

So far, I tried to set the text of `self.statusLabel` in `ProgBarDialog` class, but that doesn't work as expected. I thought I could create a loop similar to this

```python
for line in output:
    self.statusLabel.setText(line)
```

and show each line of the process output after the other. But I don't know how exactly to catch each line from the output since the output comes as a big string and because of that, of course `for line in output` catches the characters and not the lines.

How do I have to manipulate the output to format it the correct way to be able to show it in a widget (for example a `QLabel` or something similar) inside a `QDialog`?

*(it might be that the way I coded this is stupid or inefficient, so any suggests are welcome)*

---

### **Minimal reproducible example:**

*Note: A virtual environment beside `testfile.py` is needed to reproduce.*

#### *testfile.py*

```python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys
import os

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog, QVBoxLayout,
                             QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QProgressBar)


def has_bash():
    """
    Test if bash is available. If present the string `/bin/bash` is returned,
    an empty string otherwise.
    """
    res = Popen(
        ["which", "bash"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, text="utf-8"
    )
    out, _ = res.communicate()
    shell = out.strip()
    return shell

def run_script(command):
    """
    Run the script and catch output of the subprocess line by line.
    The `command` argument is set in `run_pip()`.
    """
    process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, text="utf-8")

    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        if output == "" and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output:
            # TODO: show output in dialog together with a progressbar
            print(f"[PIP]: {output.strip()}")
    rc = process.poll()
    return rc

def run_pip(cmd, opt, package, venv_dir, venv_name):
    """
    Activate the virtual environment and run pip commands.
    """
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    script = os.path.join(current_dir, "run.sh")

    if has_bash():
        # create run script
        with open(script, "w") as f:
            f.write(
                "#!/bin/bash\n"
                f"source {venv_dir}/{venv_name}/bin/activate\n"
                f"pip {cmd}{opt}{package}\n"
                "deactivate\n"
            )
        # make it executable
        os.system(f"chmod +x {script}")
        # run script
        command = ["/bin/bash", script]
        run_script(command)


class ProgBarDialog(QDialog):
    """
    Dialog showing output and a progress bar during the installation process.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(675, 365, 325, 80)
        self.setFixedSize(350, 85)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint, False)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint, False)

        h_Layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        v_Layout = QVBoxLayout()
        h_Layout.setContentsMargins(0, 15, 0, 0)

        self.statusLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.placeHolder = QLabel(self)

        self.progressBar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progressBar.setFixedSize(325, 23)
        self.progressBar.setRange(0, 0)

        v_Layout.addWidget(self.statusLabel)
        v_Layout.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        v_Layout.addWidget(self.placeHolder)

        h_Layout.addLayout(v_Layout)
        self.setLayout(h_Layout)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    cmd = ["install "]
    opt = ["--upgrade "]
    package = "pylint"  # this could be any package
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    venv_name = "testenv"  # a virtual env beside this test file

    run_pip(cmd[0], opt[0], package, current_dir, venv_name)

    #]=======================================================================[#

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    progBar = ProgBarDialog()
    progBar.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case it is better to use QProcess since it does not block the eventloop and notifies you through a signal when there is a new output:

```py
import os

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QObject, QProcess, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFontMetrics
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QProgressBar, QVBoxLayout


def has_bash():
    process = QProcess()
    process.start("which bash")
    process.waitForStarted()
    process.waitForFinished()
    if process.exitStatus() == QProcess.NormalExit:
        return bool(process.readAll())
    return False


class PipManager(QObject):
    started = pyqtSignal()
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    textChanged = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, venv_dir, venv_name, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._venv_dir = venv_dir
        self._venv_name = venv_name

        self._process = QProcess(self)
        self._process.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.onReadyReadStandardError)
        self._process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.onReadyReadStandardOutput)
        self._process.stateChanged.connect(self.onStateChanged)
        self._process.started.connect(self.started)
        self._process.finished.connect(self.finished)
        self._process.finished.connect(self.onFinished)
        self._process.setWorkingDirectory(venv_dir)

    def run_command(self, command="", options=None):
        if has_bash():
            if options is None:
                options = []
            script = f"""source {self._venv_name}/bin/activate; pip {command} {" ".join(options)}; deactivate;"""
            self._process.start("bash", ["-c", script])

    @pyqtSlot(QProcess.ProcessState)
    def onStateChanged(self, state):
        if state == QProcess.NotRunning:
            print("not running")
        elif state == QProcess.Starting:
            print("starting")
        elif state == QProcess.Running:
            print("running")

    @pyqtSlot(int, QProcess.ExitStatus)
    def onFinished(self, exitCode, exitStatus):
        print(exitCode, exitStatus)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def onReadyReadStandardError(self):
        message = self._process.readAllStandardError().data().decode().strip()
        print("error:", message)
        self.finished.emit()
        self._process.kill()
        """self.textChanged.emit(message)"""

    @pyqtSlot()
    def onReadyReadStandardOutput(self):
        message = self._process.readAllStandardOutput().data().decode().strip()
        self.textChanged.emit(message)


class ProgBarDialog(QDialog):
    """
    Dialog showing output and a progress bar during the installation process.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setFixedWidth(400)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint, False)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint, False)

        self.statusLabel = QLabel()
        self.placeHolder = QLabel()

        self.progressBar = QProgressBar()
        self.progressBar.setFixedHeight(23)
        self.progressBar.setRange(0, 0)

        v_Layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        v_Layout.addWidget(self.statusLabel)
        v_Layout.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        v_Layout.addWidget(self.placeHolder)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def update_status(self, status):
        metrix = QFontMetrics(self.statusLabel.font())
        clippedText = metrix.elidedText(status, Qt.ElideRight, self.statusLabel.width())
        self.statusLabel.setText(clippedText)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    progBar = ProgBarDialog()

    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    venv_name = "testenv"

    manager = PipManager(current_dir, venv_name)
    manager.textChanged.connect(progBar.update_status)
    manager.started.connect(progBar.show)
    manager.finished.connect(progBar.close)

    manager.run_command("install", ["--upgrade", "pylint"])

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```